# Oracle 11.2 split record to multiple record

Tags: database, oracle

Original Table:

```
N tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4 tag5 tag6 countBlankRU countBlankEN countLetterRU countLetterEN countOrderRU countOrderEn
1  y    y    y    n    n    n    50             100            10            null           null        null
2  n    y    n    y    n    n    null            50           null            50            null        null
```

I want to split to:

record 1

```
N countBlankRU
1  50
```

record 2

```
N countBlankEN
1  100
```

record 3

```
N countLetterRU
1  10
```

record 4

```
N countBlankEN
2  50
```

record 5

```
N countLetterEN
2  50
```

Comment: What are the extra columns `fieldIFtag1_2` for and how are they populated? And where is `text` coming from - is that set based on the column name? A more complete example might be useful, particularly the output you're trying to get.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. What is the `...` in your records? Where does the `text` value come from? Please also provide the query you have tried at the moment (it might help to add some clarity).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully describe the original table. fieldIFtagN_M are the fields that are in the original table in records witn N 1 and 2, but in the resulting table, after splitting, need show only those that have Y in the tagN field. ... - it's other columns, that need show if Y in tagN. "Text" - it's just a text. It is already in these columns as values.

Comment: It does matter - is the text another column in the source table?

Comment: No, "text" - value in this column (fieldIFtagN_M) in original table/record

Comment: It's still hard to see what's happening when all of those new columns you've added are null; can you show more representative data? I think I get what you're trying to do now (though ti suggests a not-ideal data model) but it would help if you clarified it.

Comment: Are there only ever 2 (or a fixed maximum number) rows in the table? If not, how do you know how many `N_M` columns are needed?

Comment: @MT0 rows - not 2, many, but columns with name "tag" - 6, and they always has 'y' or 'n'.

Comment: @Alex Poole i will try

Comment: @Alex Poole change first record - maybe it will be clearer. I'll try with UNPIVOT, very similar to what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `UNPIVOT` and filter when the value is `y` to get your records. Beyond that, it is unclear where your `text` value is coming from or what the purpose of the extra `fieldIFtagN_M` column is.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dfb8f/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( N, tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, tag6 ) AS
SELECT 1, 'y', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'n', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT N, tag, 'text'
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT ( value FOR tag IN ( tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, tag6 ) )
WHERE  value = 'y'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dfb8f/3/0)**:

```
| N |  TAG | 'TEXT' |
|---|------|--------|
| 1 | TAG1 |   text |
| 1 | TAG2 |   text |
| 1 | TAG3 |   text |
| 2 | TAG2 |   text |
| 2 | TAG4 |   text |
```

---

**Update** including some extra fields:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc126/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  N, tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, tag6,
  fieldIF1, fieldIF2, fieldIF3, fieldIF4, fieldIF5, fieldIF6
) AS
SELECT 1, 'y', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', '1,1', '1,2', '1,3', '1,4', '1,5', '1,6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'n', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', '2,1', '2,2', '2,3', '2,4', '2,5', '2,6' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT N,
       tag,
       CASE tag
       WHEN 'TAG1' THEN fieldIF1
       WHEN 'TAG2' THEN fieldIF2
       WHEN 'TAG3' THEN fieldIF3
       WHEN 'TAG4' THEN fieldIF4
       WHEN 'TAG5' THEN fieldIF5
       WHEN 'TAG6' THEN fieldIF6
       END AS fieldIF
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT (
  value FOR tag IN ( tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, tag6 )
)
WHERE  value = 'y'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc126/2/0)**:

```
| N |  TAG | FIELDIF |
|---|------|---------|
| 1 | TAG1 |     1,1 |
| 1 | TAG2 |     1,2 |
| 1 | TAG3 |     1,3 |
| 2 | TAG2 |     2,2 |
| 2 | TAG4 |     2,4 |
```

---

**Update 2** - with your updated sample data:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/804b44/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  N,
  tag1,          tag2,
  tag3,          tag4,
  tag5,          tag6,
  countBlankRU,  countBlankEN,
  countLetterRU, countLetterEN,
  countOrderRU,  countOrderEn
) AS
SELECT 1, 'y', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n',   50,  100,   10, null, CAST(null AS NUMBER(3,0)), CAST(null AS NUMBER(3,0)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'n', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', null,   50, null,   50, null, null FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT N,
       tag,
       fieldIF
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT (
  (value,fieldIf) FOR tag IN (
    (tag1, countBlankRU)  AS 'CountBlankRU',
    (tag2, countBlankEN)  AS 'CountBlankEN',
    (tag3, countLetterRU) AS 'CountLetterRU',
    (tag4, countLetterEN) AS 'CountLetterEN',
    (tag5, countOrderRU)  AS 'CountOrderRU',
    (tag6, countOrderEN)  AS 'CountOrderEN'
  )
)
WHERE  value = 'y'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/804b44/3/0)**:

```
| N |           TAG | FIELDIF |
|---|---------------|---------|
| 1 |  CountBlankRU |      50 |
| 1 |  CountBlankEN |     100 |
| 1 | CountLetterRU |      10 |
| 2 |  CountBlankEN |      50 |
| 2 | CountLetterEN |      50 |
```

Answer (score 5):

The basic structure you're looking for is an [unpivot](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__CHDJBHHI):

```
select n, tag
from your_table
unpivot(flag for tag in (tag1 as 1, tag2 as 2, tag3 as 3, tag4 as 4, tag5 as 5, tag6 as 6))
where flag = 'y';

         N        TAG
---------- ----------
         1          1
         1          2
         1          3
         2          2
         2          4
```

You can use any text you like instead of the tag number in the exmaple above, and you appear to want multiple columns, which you can also do:

```
select n, fieldiftag, fieldiftag2
from your_table
unpivot(flag for (fieldiftag, fieldiftag2) in (
  tag1 as ('tag 1 text 1', 'tag 1 text 2'),
  tag2 as ('tag 2 text 1', 'tag 3 text 2'),
  tag3 as ('tag 3 text 1', 'tag 4 text 2'),
  tag4 as ('tag 4 text 1', 'tag 5 text 2'),
  tag5 as ('tag 5 text 1', 'tag 6 text 2'),
  tag6 as ('tag 6 text 1', 'tag 7 text 2')
))
where flag = 'y';

         N FIELDIFTAG   FIELDIFTAG2 
---------- ------------ ------------
         1 tag 1 text 1 tag 1 text 2
         1 tag 2 text 1 tag 3 text 2
         1 tag 3 text 1 tag 4 text 2
         2 tag 2 text 1 tag 3 text 2
         2 tag 4 text 1 tag 5 text 2
```

Or if the text is coming from another column in the source row and you want to include that same text for each of the unpivoted rows, something like:

```
with your_table (N, tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, tag6, text) as (
            select 1, 'y', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'text from row 1' from dual
  union all select 2, 'n', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'text from row 2' from dual
)
select n, text
from your_table
unpivot(flag for tag in (tag1 as 1, tag2 as 2, tag3 as 3, tag4 as 4, tag5 as 5, tag6 as 6))
where flag = 'y';

         N TEXT           
---------- ---------------
         1 text from row 1
         1 text from row 1
         1 text from row 1
         2 text from row 2
         2 text from row 2
```

Or to pick up the text value from a different column in the source table for each tag match:

```
with your_table (N, tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, tag6,
  fieldiftag1_1, fieldiftag2_1, fieldiftag3_1, fieldiftag4_1, fieldiftag5_1, fieldiftag6_1)
as (
            select 1, 'y', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n',
              'text1_1', 'text2_1', 'text3_1', null, null, null
            from dual
  union all select 2, 'n', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n',
              null, 'text2_1', null, 'text4_1', null, null
            from dual
)
select n, text
from your_table
unpivot((flag, text) for tag in (
  (tag1, fieldiftag1_1),
  (tag2, fieldiftag2_1),
  (tag3, fieldiftag3_1),
  (tag4, fieldiftag4_1),
  (tag5, fieldiftag5_1),
  (tag5, fieldiftag6_1)))
where flag = 'y';

         N TEXT   
---------- -------
         1 text1_1
         1 text2_1
         1 text3_1
         2 text2_1
         2 text4_1
```

which you can expand for multiple text columns per tag match:

```
with your_table (N, tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, tag6,
  fieldiftag1_1, fieldiftag2_1, fieldiftag3_1, fieldiftag4_1, fieldiftag5_1, fieldiftag6_1,
  fieldiftag1_2, fieldiftag2_2, fieldiftag3_2, fieldiftag4_2, fieldiftag5_2, fieldiftag6_2)
as (
            select 1, 'y', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n',
              'text1_1', 'text2_1', 'text3_1', null, null, null,
              'text1_2', 'text2_2', 'text3_2', null, null, null
            from dual
  union all select 2, 'n', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n',
              null, 'text2_1', null, 'text4_1', null, null,
              null, 'text2_2', null, 'text4_2', null, null
            from dual
)
select n, text_1, text_2
from your_table
unpivot((flag, text_1, text_2) for tag in (
  (tag1, fieldiftag1_1, fieldiftag1_2),
  (tag2, fieldiftag2_1, fieldiftag2_2),
  (tag3, fieldiftag3_1, fieldiftag3_2),
  (tag4, fieldiftag4_1, fieldiftag4_2),
  (tag5, fieldiftag5_1, fieldiftag5_2),
  (tag5, fieldiftag6_1, fieldiftag6_2)
))
where flag = 'y';

         N TEXT_1  TEXT_2 
---------- ------- -------
         1 text1_1 text1_2
         1 text2_1 text2_2
         1 text3_1 text3_2
         2 text2_1 text2_2
         2 text4_1 text4_2
```

etc.